# Rake task what is `[] => %w[ensure_review_app environment, db:seed ]` doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

Can someone explain to me what the below `task :seed` is doing? Specifically the `[]=>%w[]` section where ensure_review_app, environment, etc are listed?  I recognize that `db:seed` is seeding the database, but confused by what the others are doing.

```
 task :seed, [] => %w[
        ensure_review_app
        environment
        db:seed
        seed:administrator
        seed:widgets
      ] do
        Rails.logger.tagged('Seed App') { |l| l.info("Finished seeding new Review App: #{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}") }
      end
```

### Rake File:

```
namespace :review_app do
  desc 'Ensure environment is one we shish to spread seed in'
  task :ensure_review_app do
    abort 'This is not a Heroku Review App' unless review_app?
  end

  desc 'Seeds a review app with a subset of realistic-looking data'
  task :seed, [] => %w[
    ensure_review_app
    environment
    db:seed
    seed:administrator
    seed:widgets
  ] do
    Rails.logger.tagged('Seed App') { |l| l.info("Finished seeding new Review App: #{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}") }
  end

  def review_app?
    !!ENV['HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME']
  end
end
```

As found here: https://gist.github.com/stevenharman/98576bf49b050b9e59fb26626b7cceff

I thought ensure_review_app might be a file, is it a heroku command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other things mentioned here are the [prerequisites](https://ruby.github.io/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Tasks+with+Prerequisites) of the task you're looking at. I.e. they are other rake tasks that should be run prior to the `:seed` task being run.

They're in a slightly odd format ( `[] => %w[...]` ) because the task is specifying that there are no arguments to the task. You can see this in the [Tasks that Expect Parameters and Have Prerequisites](https://ruby.github.io/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Tasks+that+Expect+Parameters+and+Have+Prerequisites) section of the rake docs.

Often you'd see the prerequisites straight off the task name, e.g.:

```
task seed: %w[ensure_review_app environment db:seed ... ]
```

When you choose to run that task with `rake review_app:seed` it will run all of the other prerequisite tasks first and then run the `review_app:seed` task.

You can see the `ensure_review_app` task in the longer snippet you posted. It's doing heroku stuff but it's just a rake task like any other.

You should be able to list any of the rake tasks using:

```
rake -T task_name
```

For tasks that don't have a description you might need to use `-A`:

```
rake -A -T task_name
```

Comment: what is `environment`? is that a rake task? or just outputing the environment?

Comment: It's another rake task that sets up the rails environment. I've added a bit to the answer explaining how to list tasks.